# Quora fontawesome icon not work

Tags: fontawesome

I tried to add fontawesome icon in my latex document but `\faQuora` is not working I used [This link](http://www.ipgp.fr/~moguilny/LaTeX/fontawesome5Icons.pdf) to see fontawesome icon names can anyone explain me what is wrong I have done thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Probably you are using the `fontawesome` package instead of `fontawesome5`. Replace `\usepackage{fontawesome}` by `\usepackage{fontawesome5}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've compiled following code with pdflatex and didn't see any problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\faQuora
\end{document}
```

[image]